# DLNA/UPnP client ( that stream music/video ) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, client, upnp, dlna

We have a DLNA server in Windows 8 OS.
the problem is, everybody that uses Windows, can easily stream music into the server (i mean play music from their PC's on the server), but i didn't found anything ( and i searched a lot ) in my Ubuntu 14.04 that does this and i tried **VLC**, **AudioPulse**, **Rythmebox**, ...
this applications, only shows me the current playlist that is on the server, they don't let me add music to the playlist. Does anybody knows what app i can use ? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Kodi

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install kodi`

Then follow the instructions here :

[UPnP](http://kodi.wiki/view/UPnP/Client)

[HOW-TO:Share libraries using UPnP](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Share_libraries_using_UPnP)

Answer (score 0):

Find and install VLC version 2.1.6 Rincewind. I discovered this by chance. Later versions that I have tried aren't as solid. YMMV.

https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.1.6/
My version has this md5sum
6de050559fbb1456b35303f04705145d *vlc-2.1.6.tar.xz

I run Ubuntu 14/04 LTS. VLC 2.1.6 works with minidlna on Linux, DVBViewer Pro on Win10, whatever my TP-Link router uses. a Panasonic DMR HWT 230, so pretty much anything stands a good chance.

The list of content includes repeats of each item, choose the last item in the repeated group.